# Azure: Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

Again my Azure Web App was down for quite a few minutes (at least 5-10 minutes) in the middle of the day. This was during a low load, but this is a horrible experience for customers.

Requests take forever with giving returning a 503 after a long period of time.
When I look in the logs I see low activity and low memory and CPU useage.

I've downloaded the logs and I see the following entries:

```
Role environment . INITIALIZING
Role environment . INITIALED RETURNED. HResult=-2147024891
Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891
Role environment . INITIALIZING
Role environment . INITIALED RETURNED. HResult=-2147024891
Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891
```

Does anyone know what's going on? I have two standard instances running.

Comment: Did you find out the cause? Im having the same issue. Ive  recently upgraded our projects to .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: @gorrillapower There were two things. One was that the shared storage had problems (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253899/how-does-the-azure-web-apps-architecture-look-like for more information about that). The other problems that I've had for unresponsiveness was lack of memory. Apparently you really quickly run out of memory with the smaller instances  - I assume it's because a lot of 'overhead' per instance - for i.e. IIS or something.