# What does the Azure Web Apps architecture look like?

Tags: azure, web-applications, architecture, azure-web-app-service, failover

I've had a few outages of 10 to 15 minutes, because apparently Microsoft had a 'blip' on their storages. They told me that it is because of a shared file system between the instances (making it a single point of failure?)

I didn't understand it and asked **how file share is involved**, because I would assume a really dumb stateless IIS app that communicates with SQL Azure for its data.

I would assume the situation below:

[image: Architecture I assumed]

This is their reply to my question (I didn't include the drawing)

> The file shares are not necessarily for your web app to communicate to
> another resources but they are on our end where the app content
> resides on. That is what we meant when we suggested that about storage
> being unavailable on our file servers. The reason the restarts would
> be triggered for your app that is on both the instances is because the
> resources are shared, the underlying storage would be the same for
> both the instances. That’s the reason if it goes down on one, the
> other would also follow eventually. If you really want the
> availability of the app to be improved, you can always use a traffic
> manager. However, there is no guarantee that even with traffic manager
> in place, the app doesn’t go down but it improves overall availability
> of your app. Also we have recently rolled out an update to production
> that should take care of restarts caused by storage blips ideally, but
> for this feature to be kicked it you need to make sure that there is
> ample amount of memory needs to be available in the cases where this
> feature needs to kick in. We have couple of options that you can have
> set up in order to avoid any unexpected restarts of the app because of
> a storage blip on our end:
>
> - You can evaluate if you want to move to a bigger instance so that
>   we might have enough memory for the overlap recycling feature to be
>   kicked in.
> - If you don’t want to move to a bigger instance, you can always use
>   local cache feature as outlined by us in our earlier email.

Because of the time differences the communication takes ages. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my thinking?

The only thing that I think of is that when you've enabled two instances, they run on the same physical server. But that makes really little sense to me.

I have two instances **one core, 1.75 GB memory**.

Comment: Can you link to where the answer above come from? It would be easier to keep the conversation in one place.

Comment: Hi David, the qoute from above is from the email conversation I have with Azure customer support. My question before this was "I still don't get it though. I probably thinking a bit to simple about this, but why do I need the file shares? I was just in assumption that a Web App was a dumb stateless IIS? Why would it need to access something over a network when the site is deployed (besides i.e. SQL)"

Comment: Ok, I added an answer.

Answer (score 5):

My presumption for App Service Plans was that they were automatically split into availability sets (see below for a brief description) Largely based on [Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/app-service/web/) sales spiel which states

> App Service provides availability and automatic scale on a global data centre infrastructure. Easily scale applications up or down on demand, and **get high availability within** and across different geographical regions.

Following on from David Ebbo's answer and comments, the underlying architecture of Web apps appears to be that the VM's themselves are separated into availability sets. However all of the instances use the same fileserver to share the underlying disk space. This file server being a significant single point of failure.

To mitigate this Azure have created the `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION` which will cache the contents of the file server onto the individual Web App instances. Using caching in lieu of solid, high availability engineering principles.

The problem here is that as a customer we have no visibility into this issue, we've no idea if there is a plan to fix it, or if or when it will ever be fixed since it seems unlikely that Azure is going to issue a document that admits to how badly this has been engineered, even if it is to say that it is fixed.

I also can't imagine that this issue would be any different between ASM and ARM. It seems exceptionally unlikely that there was originally a high availability solution at the backend that they scrapped when ARM came along. So it is very likely that cloud services would suffer the exact same issue.

The small upside is that now that we know this is an issue, one possible solution would be to deploy multiple web apps and have a traffic manager between them. Even if they are in the same region, different apps *should* have different backend file servers.

My first action would be to reply to that email, with a link to the Web Apps page, (and this question) with a copy of the quote and ask how to enable high availability **within** a geographic region.

After that you'll likely need to rearchitect your solution!

**Availability sets**

For virtual machines Azure will let you specify an [availability set](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/). An availability set will automatically split VMs into separate update and fault domains. Meaning that servers will end up in different server racks, and those server racks won't get updates at the same time. (it is a little more complex than that,  but that's the basics!)

Comment: Hi @MichaelB, thanks for your answer. I guess that's also where my confusion comes from. In their communication they seem to hint that multiple instances give you high availability, but in the end it apparently doesn't. I hope this doesn't mean that I need to go back to Cloud Services if I want high availability.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Web Apps do used a shared file storage. The best way to think about it is that all the instances of your app map to the same network share that have your files. So if you modify the files by any mean (e.g. FTP, msdeploy, git, ...), all the instances instantly get the new files (since there is only one set of files).

And to answer your final question, each instance does run on a separate VM.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. But this seems to introduce a single point of failure. And also a practical one (looking at the logs I've had +20 times an issue like this taking my whole web application offline - despite having two instances). Isn't the Web Apps supposed to be for enterprise solutions too? Or do I have to revert back to Cloud Services. All the MS communication seem to steer to Web Apps, when you don't need 'anything specific' in your configuration.

Comment: MS support did email me about the `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION` configuration option, but this seems to be in a very experimental phase. I've tried it and got into weird caching issues with the JS bundler. At that moment I was not really in the mood to try out experimental (undocumented) configuration flags on my production site. 

I switched to Web Apps, exactly because I don't want any exotic configurations. I'm looking for a thouroughly tested as default architecture as possible. What can you recommend?

Comment: Is there no concept of an availability set with regards to web apps? As I'm aware a write to a storage stamp is replicated directly across two other stamps do they all ultimately read from the same storage stamp? when you have multiple instances in a service plan, are those instances not spread across fault / update domains?

Comment: `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION` is becoming less and less experimental, and is more and more suggested to customers. Some info [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#turning-on-the-local-cache-feature), and expect a blog post soon. Please open separate question if you're having issues with it.

Comment: @MichaelB the VMs of the different instances are spread, but the issue here is not with the VM, but with the shared storage, which is admittedly a weaker point (and the local cache option helps mitigate it).

Comment: `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION` seems to be something of a band-aid over what can only be described as a serious flaw in the architecture of Web Apps. This means that you could deploy 20 instances (serving a few million users!) and have that entire region dependent on the availability of a single file server! I find that shocking (and I wish I was being hyperbolic!) - I think a blog on how to mitigate that issue would be infinitely more valuable.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your further explanation. I can't wait for the expert blog. I am a big fan (and usually advocate) of Azure, but I am really suprised about this. I hope you guys can also adress some of the design 
decisions about this. When I find some time I'll see if I can try to debug the issues I had with the JS bundler and the `WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION`.